# Getting error when doing an update query using joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

```
UPDATE A
SET foo = 'bar',
car = 'bmw'
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B
    ON A.col1 = B.colx
    AND A.STATUS = B.STATUS
WHERE A.nbr = '1234'
      and A.STATUS IN (K,Y)
      and A.FILE_TYPE = 'R'
```

I am trying to use the update function above but I keep getting the error it is not properly ended when I try to run it. Can someone tell me where the syntax error is?

.

Comment: If you have multiple fields to update, they should be separated by a comma.

Comment: Did it and still getting back an error that its not properly ended

Comment: postgresql or mysql? It's kinda silly, but the syntax for update statements isn't always the same in each RDBMS.

Comment: What is the purpose of the table TableB in your update statement ? It sounds like useless ... Could be simplified as follow : `UPDATE  TableA A SET foo = 'bar', car = 'bmw'
WHERE A.nbr = '1234' and A.STATUS IN (K,Y) and A.FILE_TYPE = 'R'` ?

Comment: `STATUS IN (K,Y)` is a possible **typo** should it be `'K','Y'`??

Comment: Oracle `update` syntax is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/UPDATE.html). There's no `join` clause.

Answer (score 3):

In the Oracle database, when updating a table from another table, it's often easier to use the [MERGE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement) statement.

```
MERGE INTO TableA A
USING TableB B ON (
      A.col1 = B.colx
  AND A.STATUS = B.STATUS
  AND A.nbr = 1234
  AND A.STATUS IN (K,Y)
  AND A.FILE_TYPE = 'R'
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
 SET foo = 'bar'
   , car = 'bmw';
```

Comment: Lol, it's not overkill to use merge. It's standard SQL that's probably more standarized accross the different RDBMS because it was added later to the standard. It's perfectly fine to use it without the insert. Sure, normally you'd see the target table updated with values from the source data, but Tim probably has reasons to update it with fixed values.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you *can not* `update` a join query. You may only update a table (and im some cases a *view* or a *subquery*).

Fortunately you can simple rewrite your `update` without the join by passing the condition in the `where` clause.

```
update  TableA a
set foo = 'bar',
car = 'bmw'
WHERE a.nbr = '1234'
and a.STATUS IN ('K','Y')
and a.FILE_TYPE = 'R'
and (col1, status) in (select colx,status from tableB);
```

This is the *simplest* solution for you problem as described.

*Note*  if you realy needs a *join*, e.g. if you need to update the columns of the `tableA` with the columns of the `tableB` such as

```
UPDATE A
SET a.foo = b.foo,
a.car = b.car
....
```

You may use in Oracle an [*updatable join view*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/admin/managing-views-sequences-and-synonyms.html#GUID-0CEA4437-A0E8-41E6-93DF-096437A21A01) as follows

```
update (
select a.*, b.foo new_foo, b.car new_car
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B
    ON A.col1 = B.colx
    AND A.STATUS = B.STATUS
WHERE A.nbr = '1234'
      and A.STATUS IN ('K','Y')
      and A.FILE_TYPE = 'R'
)
set foo = new_foo,
car = new_car
```

Note that the join query is enclosed in parenthesis to get the rigth syntax.

Note also that the `tableB` must have a *primary key* (or unique index) on the columns `colx,status` to be able to update. Otherwise you get exception `ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table`